# Need help on Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table_Name : Order_trans_detail

```
Order_id    Order_date  Order_qty   Item_id  order_amount
100        12-Jan-16    1            1001   20
101        13-Feb-15    4            1001   80
103        14-Mar-16    3            1001   60
104        16-Dec-15    9            1001   180
105        17-Jan-16    1            1001   20
106        18-Feb-16    4            1001   80
107        19-Feb-16    3            1001   60
108        20-Jan-15    9            1001   180
109        21-Mar-15    3            1001   60
110        21-Apr-15    3            1001   60
```

Need Query to identify how many orders placed in Month of Feb-2016 as to display Month Name and count.

Comment: Do you have any queries that you have attempted?

Comment: Then it appears you should get busy and try to write one.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `DATENAME` and `YEAR` function to extract `Month` name and `Year` from date and use it in Group by to get the `count`

```
select DATENAME(MONTH,Order_date ),YEAR(Order_date), Count(*)
From Order_trans_detail
Group by DATENAME(MONTH,Order_date ),YEAR
```

To filter the records add Where clause

```
Where DATENAME(MONTH,Order_date ) = 'february' and YEAR(Order_date) = 2016
```

To get the result in `Mon-year` format use this in `Select`

```
DATENAME(MONTH,Order_date )+'-'+cast(YEAR(Order_date) as char(4))
```

If you are using `SQL Server 2012+` to concatenate month and year use `CONCAT` function

```
CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH,Order_date ),'-',YEAR(Order_date))
```

Advantage of using `CONCAT` is that you don't need to perform *explicit conversion* when concatenating `Int` with `Varchar`